# Vlookup formula or something else?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am trying to compare two separate columns from two different sheets. If the data on the Columns A match, I am trying to pull data from Column B within the first sheet and have it outputted on sheet 3.

Examples:

**Sheet 1**

| Column A |
| --- |
| One |
| Eight |
| Six |
| Four |

**Sheet 2**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| One | 1234 |
| Two | 4321 |
| Three | 2412 |
| Four | 1965 |

**Sheet 3**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| One | 1234 |
| Eight |  |
| Six |  |
| Four | 1965 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Classical Wood  ,,, please [edit] the post ,,,,, since considering the scenario Sheet 1 is not required ,,,, Sheet 2 has both Lookup data & related values to match & pull into Sheet 3 !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` and `MATCH` combinations to get compare and get the results. In both cases, you englobe them in a `IFNA` function when there are no result found.

**VLOOKUP**

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A13,A7:B10,2,FALSE),"")
```

[image]

**INDEX and MATCH**

```
=IFNA(INDEX(B7:B10,MATCH(A13,A7:A10,)),"")
```

[image]

Bring the formulae down to fill the other cells and adapt them to your sheets.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your data begins at cell A1 for all 3 sheets, you can enter the following formula onto `cell B2` on `Sheet 3`:

```
=IF('Sheet 1'!$A2='Sheet 2'!$A2,'Sheet 2'!$B2,"No Match")
```

Then simply use the cell "drag down to copy" function to bring the formula down to the last row of your data on sheet 3.

This formula returns the value of the Sheet 2 B-column cell if The specified A-column cell in Sheet 1 matches the specified A-column cell in Sheet 2. If the two cells do not match, the formula returns the text "No match".

Comment: ,,,, do U think the way of working what you have suggested will work properly ,,, please [edit] your post & update with any proper lookup formula to avoid the Down vote !!